# JQuery function not initializing on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function on page load which initialize the slider on the page. The Problem is that on my development site every thing works fine as it should but on live site it breaks and give me following error in console.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).carouFredSel is not a function

I also tried to call this function on document ready but changing the slider through thumbnails doesn't work and if clicking on enlarge link it give me another error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).ensureLoad is not a function

here .ensureLoad is extended function which ensure the object loaded before it proceed further  which is called like this

```
$.extend({
    ensureLoad: function(handler) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if(this.complete) {
                handler.call(this);
            } else {
                $(this).load(handler);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Following is the link to development site where it works fine [[Link]](http://moebler.net.dynamicweb-cms.com/m%C3%B8bl%C3%A9r/produkt/barcelona-32-pers-sofa-36)

and here is the link to live site [[link]](http://www.mobler.dk/m%C3%B8bl%C3%A9r/produkt/twist-sofa)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is because the paths to the JS files which contain those libraries is incorrect on your live site. You just need to fix the paths.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have already checked upon the paths to js libraries and ensured the path are correct

Comment: Then the files are not being served by the webserver. If you navigate to the path directly in a browser you should see the JS source of the page. If you don't, there's your problem. You can also check the network tab to see if the  request is being loaded properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are having 2 versions of jQuery included in your page, `http://www.mobler.dk/Files/Templates/Designs/Mobler/scripts/jquery-1.12.0.js` and `http://www.mobler.dk/Files/Templates/Designs/Mobler/scripts/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js`.

Since `1.12` is included first and then the plugins, the plugins are loaded to that version of jQuery, then the `1.10` is loaded and the validation plugin. Now `jQuery` variable refers to the `1.10` version of jQuery which does not have any of the plugins which was loaded to `1.12`.

So the solution is to remove the `1.10` jQuery from the page, or use `noConflict()` properly after including `1.10` so that by default the application will use `1.12`.

Note: It looks like the second jQuery file is loaded to the element `#popupform` via the page `http://www.mobler.dk/m%C3%B8bl%C3%A9r/kontaktpopup`